# React useEffect runs every time I scroll after using hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have a hook to save `scroll` value on window scroll.
(BTW, my state object is more complicated than this example code. That's why I'm using `useReducer`. I simplified the state for this question.)

Then when I attached that hook to App, everything inside `useEffect` runs every time I scroll.
I get that `console.log(scroll)` prints every time on scroll, but why is `console.log("somethingelse")` also prints every time on scroll?

I have other codes to put inside `useEffect`, so it's a huge problem if everything inside `useEffect` runs on scroll.

How do I make only `useScroll()` related code to run on scroll, and everything else runs only on re-render like `useEffect` supposed to do?

I made CodeSandbox example below.

[image: Edit flamboyant-goodall-5f25b]

```
function App() {
  const scroll = useScroll();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(scroll);
    console.log(
      "this also runs everytime I scroll. How do I make this run only on re-render?"
    );
  });

  return ( ... );
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by run only on re-render?

Comment: Since your state is updated in useScroll and you're using it inside useEffect it's supposed to be run

Answer (score 1):

The way your code is currently written the `useEffect` code will be executed on each update. When scrolling the state is updated, so the effect will be executed.

You can pass props as the second variable to the `useEffect` to determine whether it should run or not.

So, if you create an effect like this it will run every time the scroll is updated

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This wil run on mount when scroll changes')
}, [scroll]) // Depend on scroll value, might have to be memoized depending on the exact content of the variable.
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This will only run once when the component is mounted')
}, []) // No dependencies.
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('This will run on mount and when `someStateVar` is updated')
}, [someStateVar]) // Dependent on someStateVar, you can pass in multiple variables if you want.
```

Without passing the second argument, the effect will always run on every render. You can add multiple effects in a single component. So, you'll probably want to write one containing the stuff that needs to be executed when `scroll` updates and create one or more others that only run on mount of after some variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of cleanup functions which can be attached to an useEffect hook. This cleanup function will be run once the rerender is complete. It's usually used in scenarios where you need to unsubscribe from a subscription once the render is complete. Below is the sample code from React website

```
   useEffect(() => {
  const subscription = props.source.subscribe();
  return () => {
    // Clean up the subscription
    subscription.unsubscribe();
  };
});
```

More details can be found in the blogpost
[useEffect Hook](https://daveceddia.com/useeffect-hook-examples/)